# Testcafe which remote browser did my test run in?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I use a custom browser provider - saucelabs - I'd like my custom reporter to know in which remote browser it ran so I can properly correlate the saucelabs video with a failed test.
This obviously is only an issue with concurrency > 1 :)

If a test fails which remote browser was it run in???
thanks!!
  Mark

Answer (score 1):

The [`reportTestDone`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/plugin-api/reporter.html#reporttestdone) method of a reporter plugin is called after a test is done in all browsers. If [`testRunInfo.errs`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/plugin-api/reporter.html#testruninfo-object) array is empty, it means that the test passed in all browsers. If it is non-empty, every item has a `userAgent` property, telling in which browser the error occurred.

So, if you need a list of browsers in which the test fails, you could use something like this: `_.chain(testRunInfo.errs).map('userAgent').uniq().value()`.

I didn't find this in the official documentation, though.

Comment: thanks!!!!  I know you can get which -type- of browser failed a test - for saucelabs to get the video of the failed test I need to know specifically -which- browser failed (specifically the webdriver sessionId).

Comment: @user1883202

At the moment there is no detailed information about browsers in `reportTestDone` arguments. I suggest you create a separate feature request in the TestCafe repository using the following form: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=feature_request.md](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=feature_request.md) and describe your scenario in greater detail.